# https times out, only works for xxx.appspot.com domains?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an app engine (java) project. When I try to access urls using https with a purchased domain, page serves just time out. For example, I've purchased the domain "example.com" and hooked it up to my app engine account for "example.appspot.com". So:

http://example.com   (works)

https://example.com  (times out)

https://example.appspot.com (works)

I remember there being some catch about https with domains not using the appspot pattern. Is it possible to get this to work, or we have to use the appspot pattern if we want to use https?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, **custom domains are supported**

see https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl

You need to have billing enabled and one to have cleared for it to work

Also, **there is a cost to do this**.

You can see an overview here:
https://www.globalsign.com/blog/ssl-with-google-app-engine.html

http://googleappengine.blogspot.jp/2012/06/google-app-engine-170-released-at.html

- Server Name Indication (SNI)
  This allows multiple domains to share the same IP address while still allowing a separate certificate for each domain. SNI is supported by the majority of modern web browsers. SNI is priced at $9/month which includes the serving of 5 certificates.
- Virtual IP (VIP): 
  A dedicated IP address is assigned to you for use with your applications.  VIP is supported by all SSL/TLS compatible web clients and each VIP can serve a single hostname, wildcard or multi domain certificate.  A VIP will cost $99/month.